# How to have the checkbox checked when editing my database

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a pivot table `themes_article` and when I create my `article`, its going well inside the pivot table.

What I'm trying to do now, is that when I'm editing an article, the checkbox which I've checked, need to be checked.

Here is my code :

```
@foreach ($themes as $theme)  
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="themeCheckbox[{{$theme->theme_id}}]" value="1" {{ $article->themeCheckbox[{{$theme->theme_id}}] || old('themeCheckbox[{{$theme->theme_id}}]', 0) === 1 ? 'checked' }} >
      <label class="form-check-label">{{ $theme->nom_theme }}</label>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

I'm using that to  insert my data into my pivot table (its working well) :

```
  $themes = Theme::whereIn('theme_id', array_keys($data['themeCheckbox']))->get();
  $article->save();
  $article->theme()->attach($themes);
```

My function which will update my data :

```
public function editer_article(Request $request, $idArticle)
{
    $data = $request->validate([ // $data = $this->validate($request
        'titreArticle' => 'bail|required|between:5,40',
        'typeArticle' => 'bail|required',
        'themeCheckbox' => 'required',
        'themeCheckbox.*' => 'required',
        'contenuArticle' => 'bail|required'
        
    ]);
    $type_articles = Type_article::findOrFail($data['typeArticle']);
    $article = Article::where('id_article',$idArticle)->firstOrFail();
    $article->type_article()->associate($type_articles);
    $themes = Theme::whereIn('theme_id', array_keys($data['themeCheckbox']))->get();
    $article->titre = $data['titreArticle'];
    $article->contenu = $data['contenuArticle'];

    $article->save();
    $article->theme()->sync($themes);

    return view('admin/article/admin_validation_edition');
}
```

I've got this error :

```
 syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']' (View:
```

I guess I'm not using well the condition inside the input...

Cordially

Comment: It doesn’t like the nested ‘{{ }}’ braces.

Comment: Yes but I need to put them, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes you need them, but not nested. Did you try using The suggested answer from [Stefano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65819502/281278)?

Comment: I'm really struggling since 1 week to make it work. Yes I did, I've got this error `syntax error, unexpected ')` at the line `{{ $article->themeCheckbox[$theme->theme_id] || old('themeCheckbox[$theme->theme_id]', 0) === 1 ? 'checked' }} >`

Comment: I removed one of the nested as you suggest, and now I've this : `themeCheckbox[$theme->theme_id] || old('themeCheckbox[$theme->theme_id]', 0) === 1 ? 'checked' } > conseil` and for every theme I've

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified example of how you could achieve this.

Let's assume you have models and tables for your `Article` and `Theme` objects, both of which have at least a `name` field. The convention in Laravel for naming pivot tables is to combine the singular model names in alphabetical order. So for this it would be `article_theme`. This table should at least have fields for the `article_id` and `theme_id`.

**database/migrations/create_article_theme_table.php**

```
Schema::create('article_theme', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('article_id')->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('theme_id')->constrained();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

In the `Article` model define its relationship to a `Theme`. I also added a convenience method for checking if a `Theme` was associated to the `Article` which is used in the view.

**app/Models/Article.php**

```
class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function themes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Theme::class);
    }

    /**
     * convenience function for checking if a theme is associated to the article
     */
    public function scopeHasTheme(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder, Theme $theme)
    {
        return $this->themes()->where('theme_id', $theme->id)->exists();
    }
}
```

You can do the inverse for your `Theme` model if you wish.

**app/Models/Theme.php**

```
class Theme extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }
}
```

Define some routes to show your `Article` form and another to process it.

**routes/web.php**

```
// define a route to show the form for editing an existing Article
Route::get('/articles/{article}', [\App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'show'])
    ->name('articles.show');

// define a route to process the update Article form submission
Route::put('/articles/{article}', [\App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'update'])
    ->name('articles.update');
```

Build out the functions on your `ArticleController`

**app/Http/Controllers/ArticleController.php**

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    // process the form submission
    public function update(Request $request, Article  $article)
    {
        $article->themes()->sync($request->themes);

        return redirect(route('articles.show', $article));
    }

    // display the form passing through the article and all themes
    public function show(Article $article)
    {
        return view('articles.show', [
            'article' => $article,
            'themes' => Theme::all()
        ]);
    }
}
```

The view is where the 'magic' happens. We use the `hasTheme` function on the `Article` model to check if a given `Theme` is associated with the `Article` and if so, add the `checked` attribute to a `checkbox`.

**resources/views/articles/show.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('articles.update', $article) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method("PUT")

    <h4>{{ $article->name }}</h4>

    @foreach ($themes as $theme)
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="themes[]" value="{{ $theme->id }}"  
                 id="theme-{{ $theme->id }}" @if($article->hasTheme($theme)) checked @endif>
            <label for="theme-{{ $theme->id }}">{{ $theme->name }}</label>
        </div>
    @endforeach

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

<hr>

<!-- Output the name of all themes associated to the article for reference -->
<h4>Attached Themes</h4>
@foreach ($article->themes as $theme)
    <div>
        {{ $theme->name }}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Assuming you have some `articles` and `themes` in your database, if you go to `/articles/1` for example you should see your article along with a `checkbox` for each `theme` in your database and those associated to your `article` `checked`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you dont typo. cause its hard to trace. i dont know where is your controller and what kind is that? a create or something else. and you can share more detail information...

Comment: I'm really confused about how to do this. I've got a `AdminController` with the `editer_article` (I've edited my post with the function). This is a `post` since its updating data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly outlined by @Unflux, the nested curly braces in the following snippet are not required:

```
<input
   class="form-check-input"
   type="checkbox"
   name="themeCheckbox[{{$theme->theme_id}}]"
   value="1"
   {{ $article->themeCheckbox[$theme->theme_id] || old('themeCheckbox[$theme->theme_id]', 0) === 1 ? 'checked' }} >
```

Comment: In every post I've seen, they put the braces before `$article->themeCheckbox...`, is it useless ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="gender">Gender: </label>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input class="custom-control-input" id="male" name="gender"
        type="radio" value="Male"
        {{ $dealer->gender == 'Male' ? 'checked' : '' }} />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="male">Male</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="female"
        name="gender" value="Female"
        {{ $dealer->gender == 'Female' ? 'checked' : '' }} />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="female">Female</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="na"
        name="gender" value="NotApplicable"
        {{ $dealer->gender == 'NotApplicable' ? 'checked' : '' }} />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="na">N/A</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not understand... I've got a pivot table `themes_articles`, I have no reference to `theme` inside my `article` table. Plus, I've got a `foreach` loop which will display every checkbox. I'm really confuses and really don't understand the system to do it...

Comment: What does `dealer` in your case ? The pivot table ?